# How to find out default credentials for Jasig CAS server?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I have installed Jasig CAS server but I am not able to login into it.

Can any one please tell me **the default credentials**? How to find out credentials?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use default account with same username and password
2. If you use account in LDAP or DB you can config deployerConfigContext.xml file in path : cas\WEB-INF, example with LDAP :

   - Step1: add library support ldap in pom.xml :

     org.jasig.cas
     cas-server-support-ldap
     3.5.2

   org.springframework.ldap
       spring-ldap-core
       1.3.2.RELEASE

   - Step 2: in deployerConfigContext.xml file find line :
             
     replace it with :
   - Step 3: add 1 bean before  tag to connect LDAP :



         
             ldap://10.0.0.11:2389
         




         
             
                 
                     java.naming.security.authentication
                 
                 simple

Select edit to see full, Hope it help you, cheer !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with *Jagis CAS* server, but you may need to look at your deployment configuration file, *`deployerConfigContext.xml`* where you may find the default credentials in some authentication bean.